# Flashing /waterproof for wires going through roof gable

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing, flashing

I am in the process of replacing my siding and found an odd (read: wtf) spot where wires are coming through the roof to a porch below. It looks like they just put a hole through the roof/shingles but it’s at an interesting spot where I’m not sure how to best seal it and waterproof. It’s about 5” from the adjoining wall of the second story of the colonial.[image]

Debating using something like flashing for vent pipe/conduit but don’t really see a solid solution.

[image]

Comment: Are they wires or cables?   Where do they go? Looks like the work of a cable or satellite installer. Terrible. I won't let those hacks anywhere near my house.

Comment: Can you confirm that at least one of those is a line voltage wire?

Answer (score 1):

Yuck... Given you have the siding off can you relocate the wires into the wall behind the siding?